# Inserting duplicate record in Master-Detail Tables using Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have the following Database Structure

```
    Table1
============
T1ID
Fld1

    Table2
============
T2ID
T1ID(Foreign Key from Table1)
Fld1

    Table3
============
T3ID
T2ID(Foreign Key from Table2)
Fld1
```

Now first I will filter `Table2` and `Table3` data based on `T1ID`.

After that I am required to duplicate these filtered record in the same tables. I want to accomplish this using stored procedure. I have seen examples in which data is duplicated in one table but I don't have idea how to achieve this in these two master detail tables.

Comment: Are T1ID, T2ID, T3ID identity fields in the respective tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @T1ID int = 1

declare @T table(OldT2ID int, NewT2ID int)

merge Table2 as T
using (select T2ID, Fld1
       from Table2
       where T1ID = @T1ID) as S
on (0 = 1)
when not matched then
  insert (T1ID, Fld1) values (@T1ID, S.Fld1)
output S.T2ID, inserted.T2ID into @T;

insert into Table3(T2ID, Fld1)
select T.NewT2ID, T3.Fld1
from Table3 as T3
  inner join @T as T
    on T3.T2ID = T.OldT2ID
```

Comment: The inner join bit of the `insert into Table3` seems unnecessary. Just `where T3.T2ID = @CurT2ID` would probably be enough.

Comment: @Andriy Of course, that is enough. What I really would like to do here is something that removes the loop. Like using the output clause of the insert statement to get a hold of the new T2ID's but I can't figure out a way of getting the old T2ID's added to the output so I have the connection between the old and the new id.

Comment: @Mikael: Neither can I so far. And to think that a tiny `tmplink int` column could help immensely! We've got a bigger relationship chain in one of our projects, where replicating is implemented with nested cursors. So unsettling.

Comment: @Andriy: Added a version that does not use a loop. Would be interesting to know what you think about it. Looks quite useful to me.

Comment: @Mikael: My knowledge of MERGE is so incomplete that you can hardly trust my opinion even though I'm really grateful to you for your trust. Anyway, I can see how you are using MERGE and this is exactly what couldn't be done with `INSERT...OUTPUT`, because the latter restricts us to use only `INSERTED` columns in the OUTPUT clause, while MERGE, as I can see, allows us to include columns from the source. I hope it's a valid use, because it's just great! I've got only one small question: wouldn't `MERGE ... OUTPUT columns INTO @T` be the same as `INSERT INTO @T ... FROM (MERGE...OUTPUT columns)`?

Comment: @Andriy Yes. `insert into @T` and `output into @T` does the same thing. I posted a version with `insert into` first but changed because it looked nicer with `output into` instead.

Comment: @Mikael: I must admit, I usually skipped over questions and those parts in answers that used MERGE, instead of learning on them. But you've invited me to it so nicely and the result is, I've learnt a really great thing. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that T1ID, T2ID, T3ID are identities with positive increment. I'm using two tricks:

1) when inserting new values into a table to distinguish old values from new, I'm using the value of the identity column. If it's more then the last seen maximum, then it's a newly inserted value. However for this to stay true we need to make sure that no other values was added to the table, thus I'm setting the isolation level of transaction to serializable.

2) I'm creating a temporary column in table2 so that I can keep track of old t2id against newly inserted ones. I drop the column at the end of the operation.

And now the code:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[DoIt]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[DoIt]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DoIt]
    @T1ID int
AS
BEGIN
    declare @T1IDString nvarchar(10) = cast(@T1ID as nvarchar(10))
    declare @sql nvarchar(255)
    declare @Table2max nvarchar(10)

    set transaction isolation level serializable
    begin transaction

    select @Table2max = cast(max(T2ID) as nvarchar(10)) from Table2

    exec dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'alter table Table2 add [oldT2ID] [int] null'

    set @sql = N'insert into Table2 (T1ID,fld1,oldT2ID) select T1ID,fld1,T2ID from Table2 where T1ID = ' + @T1IDString

    EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = @sql

    set @sql = N'insert into Table3 select t2.T2ID, t3.fld1 from Table3 t3 join Table2 t2 on t3.T2ID = t2.oldT2ID where t2.T1ID = ' 
        + @T1IDString + ' and t2.T2ID > ' + @Table2max
    exec dbo.sp_executesql @statement = @sql

    exec dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'alter table Table2 drop column [oldT2ID]'
    commit transaction

END

GO
```